# Configuring apache with fastcgi in Haskell

Tags: apache, haskell, centos, fastcgi

I am trying to run my Haskel fastcgi program with apache (Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Cent OS 6)),

Following are the changes done in httpd.conf

```
<IfModule fastcgi_module>
        AddHandle fastcgi-script .fcgi
</IfModule>

LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@<hostname>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName <hostname>
    ErrorLog logs/<hostname>.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/<hostname>-access_log common
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

        <Directory "/var/www/http">
                Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
                AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I followed all the instructions as specified [here](http://passingcuriosity.com/2009/haskell-fastcgi-with-apache/)

When I visit the link curl --include http:// hostname/cgi-bin/test.fcgi

I get error in apache server log as

> [error] Premature end of script headers: test.fcgi

How can I debug this issue ?

Comment: can you run your cgi standalone?, it sounds like you have a stdout writing somewhere where you shouldn't.